# resize parent window if iframe height exceeds

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using javascript to dynamically changing the height of iframe according to its content

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

<iframe id ="iframe" scrolling="no" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'>
        <p>Iframe not supported,go get a new browser</p>
</iframe>
```

Now if the iframe page height is such that the total height of other content + iframe page exceeds the height of window itself the lower part of page is trimmed,such that the bottom content of iframe is not visible.

How to solve this.

Comment: Can users still scroll down to see the bottom content?

Comment: Modern day browsers do not let you resize a browser window if you did not create it. I am so glad for that. Solution: Do not make the iframe bigger than the parent or let the parent scroll the page.

Comment: @Markasoftware no scroll bar is visible in parent window

Comment: @epascarello I am not hitting any cross domain issue,all the code is loaded by my own site

Comment: I said NOTHING about cross domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a way to stop the iframe from becoming too big. For example, if you want to stop the iframe from becoming more than 700 pixels high here is what you should do:

```
function resizeIframe(obj){
    var newheight=obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    obj.style.height=newheight>700?'700px':newheight+'px';
}
```

Comment: I am now using jquery.load() and removed the iframe altogether,still having the same problem.